# ImportError: libavcodec.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables

I am working on a python project and I am sadly experienced that once I attempt to run the script from the PyCharm ide I get the following error message:

```
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libavcodec.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now running the same python script from terminal runs without any error so I feel pretty confident that every requirement is installed properly. Therefore I turned my attention to environment variables but I am not completely sure what should the name and value be of the variable I am supposed to add to pycharm environment variable list. I run the following command:

```
whereis libavcodec.so.57
```

and I got:

```
libavcodec.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so
```

So I guess that has something to do with the the value of the env variable I am supposed to add to PyCharm.

Can anybody help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the way you install the `openCV`.

Try the following command to install `openCV` correctly:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python-opencv; sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my `ubuntu 19.10` system has `libavcodec.so.58` and not `libavcodec.so.57.`  I had a similar issue with package `digiKam.`

I solved it, crudely, in terminal window going to the folder containing `libavcodec.so,` by using:

`sudo ln -s libavcodec.so.58.35.100 libavcodec.so.57`

(I also had to do similar step with `libavutils.so`)

I realize this symbolic link will not be updated during system upgrades and is not an ideal solution.  The version numbers may also be different on your system.

When I checked into `PyCharm Community Edition,` I noticed it is invoked using a `.sh` script.  Using a Terminal Window would execute `.bashrc` each time and it may contain `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/my_lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH.`  That may explain some of the differences with your `python` `import` behaviour.  I could not reproduce your exact problem with package `opencv-python.`